# matlab GUIDE: storing data from loop in vector

Tags: matlab, user-interface, vector

I am new to matlab and i need some help. I am trying to make some program, where you can by 2 clicks on picture get a lenght of something. Basicly it works well, but got a problem when trying to algorytmize it. I use `ginput` to get coordinates and then pythagorean theorem to work with them and make important variable `z2`. And those variables I want to store in vector so basicly: I pressed `push_button1` click twice on a picture and get some z2,now when i do the procedure again i want to store the new one with the old one in the same vector 
`[z2_old z2_new]`. But basicly every time i tried to make something like this the old ones value is rewritten.

This is the code of my push button:

function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, EventData, handles)

```
%counter - number of press (working right)
counter = get(hObject, 'UserData') + 1;
set(hObject, 'UserData', counter);
set(handles.text1, 'String', sprintf('%d', counter));
```

% - ginput part (working right)

```
c2 = ginput(2);
   q3 = text(c2(1,1),c2(1,2),'X', ...
                'HorizontalAlignment','center', ...
                'Color', [1 1 0], ...
                'FontSize',10);
   q4 = text(c2(2,1),c2(2,2),'X', ...
                'HorizontalAlignment','center', ...
                'Color', [1 1 0], ...
                'FontSize',10);
```

%creating the z2 variable(working right)

```
x2=c2(1,1)-c2(2,1);
y2=c2(1,2)-c2(2,2);
z2=sqrt(x2*x2+y2*y2);
```

% - loop for getting a vector (not ok)

```
for i=1:counter        
    z(i,1)=z2                
end
```

So, basicly when I run the button first time and z2 got for example 130, second time 60, third time 210m I want to get z=[130 60 210], now I am still getting something like 1st press:z=[130], 2nd press: z=[60 60], 3rd press: z=[210 210 210], the old values are every time lost. I tried to fix it many ways but its still not working. Its only a small part of my work and i almost run out of time.

Can someone please tell me how should that loop look like? I tried `z(end+1)=z2` , `z=[z z2]` , but the result is always the same.

Thanks for your help a lot. I really Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that with each click on pushbutton, it creates new values for `z2`. Even though the counter increments, but `z2` is always the new value. So, you need to save `z2` between clicks on the pushbutton. For that you have `handles` structure available for data storage between GUI callbacks. You need to make two changes -

Add this line inside the `guiname__OpeningFcn` before the handles structure is updated in `guidata(hObject, handles);` -

```
handles.z2 =[];
```

Edit the pushbutton callback to this -

```
x2=c2(1,1)-c2(2,1)
y2=c2(1,2)-c2(2,2)
z2=sqrt(x2*x2+y2*y2)

z = [handles.z2 z2]

handles.z2 = z;
guidata(hObject,handles);
```

Hope this works out for you, let us know!

Comment: Thanks you for your help Divakar, this code is working well for me now. I wish I was enaugh experienced to find out that by myself. Everything is working now. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
Remove the for loop
Just write
z[z,z2]

This should add z2 to the end of the existing z every time.
In case it throws an error just first give z(0)=0; an initial garbage value to start with.

Comment: Thanks for help, but it didnt work for me, but I fixed my problem adding ´handles.z2 =[];´ to openfcn and using ´z = [handles.z2 z2] handles.z2 = z;´ , using the Divakar answer.  I really appreciate your help.